# Removal of select subtitle tracks and audio tracks from mkv file in batch

Tags: video, video-editing, subtitles, video-encoding, matroska

My problem is that I have 2 subtitle tracks, one is named "English signs and songs" and another is called "English full". I also have English and Japanese audio tracks (dual audio).

I need to downscale the videos to PSP resolution and I'm using handbrake for that. For my subtitle selection behavior I've made it as first matching selected language;english;burn-in behavior=first track.

However even after using that it selects signs and songs as the burned in subtitle. However signs and songs are a blank subtitle. Since it is automatically selected it's very hard to change the subtitle for each of the 200+ videos I'm converting.

So is there a way to automatically choose English full subtitle or perhaps remove signs and songs subtitles completely?

I'm aware I can do it individually in handbrake itself, but it will consume too much time.

edit: i want to expand on my question- what i actually want is to completely delete the "english-signs and songs" subtitle without reencoding the whole video.i only want to remove the subtitle track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ffmpeg in combination with a batch or powershell script to automate your goal.

Take a look here at the commands you can use with ffmpeg:
https://newbedev.com/how-to-remove-one-track-from-video-file-using-ffmpeg

Here is an example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZWxWkl7yq0

**Batch to remove Track 1 subtitle (Without Re-encoding):**

```
@echo off

IF /i exist "%~1" (set "Folder=%~1") else (exit)

pushd "%Folder%"

For /f "Delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.mkv *.mp4 *.avi *.mpg') do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -map 0 -map -0:s:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy "%%~na_NEW%%~xa"
```

**Batch to remove subtitle track 1 & change resolution to PSP (480x272) (need Re-encoding):**

```
@echo off

IF /i exist "%~1" (set "Folder=%~1") else (exit)

pushd "%Folder%"

For /f "Delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.mkv *.mp4 *.avi *.mpg') do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vf "scale=480:-1" -map 0 -map -0:s:0 -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -c:s copy "%%~na_NEW%%~xa"
```

**Considering the following videos:**

Video

**Audio:**

Audio Japanese [Index 0]

Audio English  [Index 1]

**Subtitiles:**

English        [Index 0]

Italian        [Index 1]

Spanish (Spain)[Index 2]

Spanish (Latin)[Index 3]

Brazilian Portuguese [Index 4]

Russion        [Index 5]

Arabic         [Index 6]

English Full   [Index 7]

English Sing/Song [Index 8]

**- To remove all audio but Japanese and all subtitles but English Full:**

Remove English audio (index 1): -map -0:a:1

Remove remove all subtitles: -map -0:s

Add subtitle English Full (index 7) : -map 0:s:7

```
@echo off

IF /i exist "%~1" (set "Folder=%~1") else (exit)

pushd "%Folder%"

For /f "Delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.mkv *.mp4 *.avi *.mpg') do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -map 0 -map -0:a:1 -map -0:s -map 0:s:7 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy "%%~na_NEW%%~xa"
```

**- To remove Japanese audio and English Full Subtitles:**

Remove Japanese audio (index 0): -map -0:a:0

Remove English Full subtitles (index 7): -map -o:s:7

```
@echo off

IF /i exist "%~1" (set "Folder=%~1") else (exit)

pushd "%Folder%"

For /f "Delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.mkv *.mp4 *.avi *.mpg') do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -map 0 -map -0:a:0 -map -0:s:7 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy "%%~na_NEW%%~xa"
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129315/discussion-on-answer-by-ricardo-bohner-removal-of-select-subtitle-tracks-and-aud).